# How to display one by one images when click the next button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have images in a array but it return the NULL

I have use this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    images= [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                        nil] retain];  
}
-(IBAction)Next
{
    currentImage++;
    if(currentImage >= [images count])
    {
        currentImage=0;
    }

    UIImage *img=[images objectAtIndex:currentImage];
    [animalphoto setImage:img];
    NSLog(@"print:%@",currentImage);
}
```

first time click button images display but second time not display image and that return NULL value.. give any suggestion and source code which is apply in our code.

Answer (score 0):

Add validation code in your `viewDidLoad` method to check that the images are being loaded correctly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    images= [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                        nil] retain];  
    NSAssert([images count] == 4, @"Failed to load one or more images");
}
```

Your `IBAction` method should have a `sender` parameter though, shouldn't it?

```
-(IBAction)Next:(id)sender
{
    currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % [images count];
    NSLog(@"currentImage=%d",currentImage);
    UIImage *img=[images objectAtIndex:currentImage];
    [animalphoto setImage:img];
}
```

Your code looks OK to me (but I am Mac developer) so I suspect it's a packaging issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method and currentImage = 0:

```
 -(IBAction)Next
{

  if(currentImage>=[images count])
  {
    currentImage=0;
  }

UIImage *img=[images objectAtIndex:currentImage];
[animalphoto setImage:img];
NSLog(@"print:%@",currentImage);
currentImage++;

}
```

Comment: That will cause an exception; the test should be: `if(currentImage >= [images count])`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is exactly right what you have written except you print the currentImage because currentImage is integer type but you mentioned "`%@`" string type in NSLog. That's why it shows error. You just change that one as following as

```
NSLog(@"print:%d",currentImage);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.